# Join doesn't convert the splat argument into a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Let's say we have this code:

```
def something(*someargs)
      return *someargs.join(",")
end
```

Now, I found you can reference *someargs just like any other variable anywhere in the method definition. But I tried this...returning *someargs as a string, separated with a comma. Yet, when I call this method:

```
a = something(4, 5)
p a.class # => Array
p a #> ["4,5"]
```

why does something(4,5) still returns an array? If I do something like this:

```
[4, 5].join(",")
```

the result will be a string not in an array. So my question would be, how do I make the "something" method return an actual string which contains all the arguments as a string. And it's weird because if I do *someargs.class, the result is "Array", yet it doesn't behave like a typical array...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below :

```
def something(*someargs)
      return someargs.join(",")
end
a = something(4, 5)

p a.class # => String
p a # => "4,5"
```

One example to explain your case:

```
a = *"12,11"
p a # => ["12,11"]
```

So when you did `return *someargs.join(",")`, `someargs.join(",")` created the string as `"4,5"`.But now you are using splat operator(*) again on the evaluated string `"4,5"` with the assignment operation like `a = *"4,5"`. So finally you are getting `["4,5"]`.

Read more scenarios with splat operators here - [**`Splat Operator in Ruby`**](http://www.jacopretorius.net/2012/01/splat-operator-in-ruby.html)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -3):

- An object prepended with a splat `*...` is not an object. You cannot reference such thing, nor can you pass it as an argument to a method because there is no such thing. However, if you have a method that can take multiple arguments, for example `puts`, then you can do something like:

  ```
  puts *["foo", "bar"]
  ```

  In this case, there is no such thing as `*["foo", "bar"]`. The splat operator is expanding it into multiple arguments. It is equivalent to:

  ```
  puts "foo", "bar"
  ```
- Regarding why `someargs` remains to be an array after `someargs.join(",")`. That is because `join` is not a destructive method. It does not do anything to the receiver. Furthermore, an object cannot change its class by a destructive method. The only way to change the reference of `someargs` from an array to a string is to reassign it.